# Getting number of files in directory IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I get the number of files in the whole IOS directory with the extension .png, .ext, .annotate...?? I tried this:

```
NSFileManager * filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray * filelist = [filemgr directoryContentsAtPath:yourPath error:nil];
int count = [filelist count];
NSLog("%d", count);
```

but it gives the total count, not just the one of the files with the extension

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPredicate) to filer an array with [`filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJJDBEB)

```
NSArray *extensions = @[@"png", @"ext", @"annotate"];
filelist = [filelist filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension IN %@", extensions]];
```

---

your question is not clear about if you want the combined count of all designated extensions at once (code above) or for each. that could be

```
NSArray *extensions = @[@"png", @"ext", @"annotate"];
for(NSString *ext in extensions) {
    filelist = [filelist filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension LIKE %@", ext]];
    NSLog(@"%d", [filelist count])
}
```

Comment: so NSArray *extensions = @[@"png"];
    NSArray *files = [extensions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension IN %@", extensions]];
    int count = [files count];
    NSLog(@"%d", count);
??

Comment: you also should not omit the error parameter. instead check for any error.